# remove data before and after a special characters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

In SSTS I want to remove data before "\" and after "\". Please see the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grM7L.png). We want to do it from SSRS not from SQL SP. Is it possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove special char dynamically in ssrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49202374/remove-special-char-dynamically-in-ssrs)

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://vmdp.blogspot.dk/2011/02/converting-rtf-to-txt-in-ssrs-removing.html) can be a good start - converting RTF to TXT